# real analysis and arithmetic progression

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which takes positive and negative values​​. Given $ n>2 $ natural, prove that there are $a_1, a_2, a_3 \cdots a_n$ real numbers in arithmetic progression, such that
\begin{equation}
f(a_1) + f(a_2) + \cdots + f(a_n) = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Perhaps you might like to tell us what in-roads you have made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ takes negative and positive values, there exist $x_-, x_+ \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_-) < 0$ and $f(x_+) > 0$. By continuity, for a small $\varepsilon > 0$ all the values $f(x_- + k\varepsilon)$ are negative ($k = 1,\ldots,n$) and all the values $f(x_+ + k\varepsilon)$ are positive ($k = 1,\ldots,n$). Let 
$$g(x) := \sum_{k=1}^n f(x+k\varepsilon).$$
Then $g$ is continuous and satisfies $g(x_-) < 0$ and $g(x_+) > 0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is an $x_0$ such that $g(x_0) = 0$. Let $a_k = x_0 + k\varepsilon$ ($k=1,\ldots,n$). Then the $a_k$ are in arithmetic progressions and satisfy
$$f(a_1) + \ldots + f(a_n) = 0.$$